# Can over whipped egg whites be used in other ways?

Tags: baking, egg-whites, omelette

As a beginner baker, I have always wanted to try whipping eggs to different stages so that I can grasp at which point egg whites goes over the stiff peak and becomes unusable. Not wanting to waste food, I am wondering, can the over whipped egg whites then be used for something like an omelette?

Comment: I suspect (but haven't confirmed), that once you have overwhippend them to the point of breaking most of the protein chains, you could add them to basically anything that called for adding a little water (eg bread)

Answer (score 2):

It should be easily usable in applications where the egg texture is not that important. Find a recipe which needs both eggs (not whipped) and a liquid, and add the liquid to the overwhipped egg until the foam has subsided. Add the yolks back in (such recipes generally call for whole eggs).

This should work with different types of griddle cakes: pancakes, waffles, crepes. Also with the liquid used to top moussaka etc., or the liquid used to create straciatella soups.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to cook an omelette. It worked perfectly for me, except I have added some extra vegies to it.